# Generating APK from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm trying to generate an APK from Android Studio. I go to `Build` -> `Generate signed APK`. I get the dialog, and in the last step it says: "NOTE: Proguard settings are specified using the Project Structure Dialog", and asks for APK Destination Folder, Build type and by default is selected `release` and in Flavors says "No product flavors defined".

I click `Finish` but I get the following error:

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.
> File 'geovanni_geopath_keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.
```

This is all the log:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42000Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices5077Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:app:packageRelease FAILED
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageRelease'.
> File 'geovanni_geopath_keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 9.51 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I have no idea why I get this error, it says that File [APK file name] specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.geopath'
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-1.1.5-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-1.1.5-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-1.1.5.jar')
}
```

This is my `Manifest` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geopath"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.geopath.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.geopath.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="false"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Google API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any help I will really appreciate, thanks!!!

Comment: check if your keystore exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It couldn't find the keystore. Verify if the keystore is in the right folder, if you've not deleted or renamed it.